# Xpath: how do you select the second text node (specific text node)

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

consider a html page

```
<html>
apple

orange

drugs

</html>
```

how can you select orange using xpath ?

```
/html/text()[2]
```

doesn't work.

Comment: You don't have several text nodes here. You have a single text node that contains line breaks.

Comment: what if the texts are separated via <br> ?

Comment: XPath doesn't work on HTML - it work s on XML. Unless your HTML is really XHTML, you're not going to get any good results

Answer (score 3):

You cant do it directly by selecting. You need to call an xpath string function to cut the text() to get the string you want

```
substring-after(/html/text()," ") // something like this,
```

here is a [list of string functions](http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xpath_string_functions.cfm)

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are separated with `<br>` it works

```
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML("""<html>
  apple
  <br>
  orange
  <br>
  drugs
  </html>""")
  p doc.xpath('//text()[2]') #=> orange
```